# Making a vector element into a string for comparison?

Tags: c++, vector

I'm kind of confused with vectors in C++; this is my first time using them. I made a vector of strings, and I am trying to compare elements in that vector against a letter.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

/* Head ends here */
void displayPathtoPrincess(int n, vector <string> grid){
    for(vector<string>::iterator it = grid.begin(); it != grid.end(); ++it) {
        if(*it.strcompare('p') != 0)
            cout << 'Princess found!';
    }
}

/* Tail starts here */
int main() {

    int m;
    vector <string> grid;

    cin >> m;

    for(int i=0; i<m; i++) {
        string s; cin >> s;
        grid.push_back(s);
    }

    displayPathtoPrincess(m,grid);

    return 0;
}
```

Why won't this work? Won't *it always be a string type?

Here is my error:

```
error: 'std::vector >::iterator' has no member named 'strcompare'
```

Comment: In what way does it *not work*?

Comment: what is `strcompare`?

Comment: Does this even compile?

Comment: Sorry I'm dumb and forgot to post the compile log. =\

Comment: You probably meant (*it).strcompare or it->strcompare. Although you actually should just use `==`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, in this context, `.` binds tighter than `*`, so this

```
*it.strcompare('p')
```

is equivalent to

```
*(it.strcompare('p'))
```

so you should call something like

```
it->methodName(args)
```

Second, you need to call a method of [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), presumably [`std::string::compare`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/compare).

Note that if all you want to do is search for an entry equal to `"p"`, then all you have to do is

```
auto it = std::find(grid.begin(), grid.end(), "p");
if (it != v.end()) std::cout << "Princess found!" << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `strcompare` in the Standard Library.

Perhaps you meant `compare`?

Also, yes `*it` will be a `string` -- but `'p'` is not.  That is a `char`.  You need to either convert `'p'` to a `string` (eg `string s(1,'p')`) or compare the first (or last) character in `*it` to `'p'` (eg `(*it)[0] == 'p'` -- warning, unsafe as is)

Finally, others have already mentioned this, but `*it.strcompare` would not bind as `(*it).strcompare`, but rather as `*(it.strcompare)`.  Meaning, you are trying to call a method called `strcompare` on the *iterator*, rather than what the iterator refers to.  Even if `string` had a method called `strcompare` (which it doesn't), your code still wouldn't compile.

Comment: Thanks man. I'm just getting a junk number now  (197016886519701688651970168865) but it solved my compile errors.

Answer (score 0):

The class std::string is basic_string ( http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string ) and I do not think this class has a standard strcompare member function(Though some compilers do provide one).

I think you are trying to do something like:

```
if(*it == String("P"))
```

Which can more simply be written as:

```
if(*it == "P")
```

for an example: http://ideone.com/isa9Il

Comment: True, but alas, this involves needless construction of a `std::string`

Comment: I think that most modern compilers would optimize out much of the costs of that. Even if not the simplicity might be worth the cost depending on context. Now you have made me want to write a benchmark.